# ошибка с модификатором mb_substr в php Smarty 2

Tags: php, smarty

Переношу сайт на новый хостинг, в логе веб-сервера ошибка

```
PHP Fatal error:  Smarty error: [in header.tpl line 64]: [plugin] modifier 'mb_substr' is not implemented (core.load_plugins.php, line 118) in /var/www/mydomain.tk/html/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1100
```

В файле header.tpl строка 64

```
<span><b>{$language.lang_short_name|mb_substr:0:2:'utf-8'}</b></span>
```

В Smarty.class.php в строке 1100

```
trigger_error("Smarty error: $msg", $error_type);
```

В файле core.load_plugins.php

```
        if ($_found) {
            $smarty->_plugins[$_type][$_name] = array($_plugin_func, $_tpl_file, $_tpl_line, true, true);
        } else {
            // output error
            $smarty->_trigger_fatal_error('[plugin] ' . $_message, $_tpl_file, $_tpl_line, __FILE__, __LINE__);
        }
```

Comment: `mbstring` модуль включен в пхп?

Comment: нет, не был установлен, после установки ошибка исчезла. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в смарти через черту `{$var|modifier}` могут указываться как модификаторы (плагины смарти), такие как `{$var|escape}` так и обычные функции php.

`mb_substr` это функция пхп из модуля mbstring. Поскольку при вызове происходит ошибка, то вывод один - модуль не подключен в php.ini.